# Issue in blocking user in chatlist using smack library and open fire server

Tags: xmpp, privacy, smack

I want to block a particular friend from my chat list with XMPP. My code for doing this:

```
public void blockUser(String userName)
{
    String listName = "newList";
    List<PrivacyItem> privacyItems = new Vector<PrivacyItem>();
    PrivacyItem item=new PrivacyItem(PrivacyItem.Type.jid.toString(), false, 1);   
    item.setValue(userName);    
    privacyItems.add(item);   

    privacyManager = PrivacyListManager.getInstanceFor(mXMPPConnection);

    try
    {
    privacyManager.createPrivacyList(listName,privacyItems);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
   Log.e("PRIVACY_ERROR: "," "+e.toString());
   e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

code works fine. There is no Exception, but I am not able to block a user. Can anyone help me?

Smack Logs which I got:

```
<main><iq type="set" id="373-3717" to="nitstest1@hostname/smack"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:privacy"><list name="newList"/></query></iq>
09-04 19:00:38.368: D/SMACK(3895): 07:00:38 PM SENT (1149259528): <iq id="373-3717" type="result"></iq>
09-04 19:00:38.658: D/SMACK(3895): 07:00:38 PM RCV  (1149259528): <iq type="result" id="LvJcf-9" to="nitstest1@hostname/smack"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:privacy"><list name="newList"><item action="deny" order="1" type="jid" value="nitsquytech@hostname"/></list></query></iq></main>
```

Comment: Code and XMPP stanzas look good. Have you verified that the server enforces the privacy list? It looks like a server issue to me.

Comment: i m using open fire server. what changes should i made on server so that i get desired result.

Comment: Hi guys, I faced same problem if any changes need in server side.If it  is any changes please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the privacy list you created to be the active list.